# Why does youtube etc use <object> and not <iframe>?

Tags: html, css, iframe, object-tag

Why does youtube etc use `<object>` and not `<iframe>`?

What are the advantages of object over iframe for this case?

Comment: Why do you think it should use an `<iframe>`?

Comment: I dont think, I beginer.

Comment: `*ROFL*`... Of course. Beginners don't think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `iframe`s are for embedding other HTML pages within a page.
- `object`s are for embedding non-HTML content objects (like Flash) within a page.

Since YouTube is using Flash to play videos, it uses `object`.